# Close votes remaining?

Tags: discussion, faq, closed-questions

when voting to close I saw this:

[image]

What is the purpose of limiting close votes? Is this how many I have for ever or do they refresh every 24 hours?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That number is how many you have for a period of 24 hours. [The purpose of this is the same as the rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap), which is to keep users in check and to make sure you don't burn out.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.